# Use native search field as drop area

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm looking for a way to add a drop handler to the native spotify search field. So when the user tries to add a track he can drop it not only in the area in my app but also in the native search field.

My app was rejected because it couldn't do that so it seems that this is possible. But I couldn't find a way on how to do it.

Does anybody know how the handler is added?

Comment: Are you sure you tagged this question properly? What language are you building the App in?

Comment: Yes, I am. html5/javascript. Look here: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the native search field as in the thing in the top left of the client, rather than a control you added to your own?

If so then no, you can't modify the behaviour of Spotify's own search field.

Comment: Just saw you're from Spotify. Forget what I wrote. So your QA team is demanding something we can't do. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I imagine either you or they misinterpreted something. Since you have contact with our QA team, you should ask them for clarification.

Comment: We already did. That's what came back: "We are referring to the native Spotify search input field. Sorry for being unclear about this." So I don't think there is much space to misinterpret the task.